# How to monitor a CAN signal continuously using CAPL?

Tags: c++, c, can-bus, capl

There is a signal named 'A' which counts from 0 to 20 of a specified occurrence. The signal will reset to 0 after it counts 20. The time interval between each occurrence is 20 ms.
I need to monitor this signal *A* for 200 times. Whenever the counter skips a value ,say for example: 0,1,4,5..20 ,I need to to store that particular instance. Is there anyway to do this? Is there any commands in CAPL to catch the value of the counter signal *A* whenever it changes.?

Comment: Could you please show what you have done so far?

Comment: @M.Spiller  Its not yet developed. Do these commands will  help testWaitForMessage and getSignal ?

Comment: So you are developing code for a Test node (you mention testWaitForMessage)? Or is your code supposed to be run in a simulation/measurement node? You do not mention that in your question.

Comment: Sorry @M.Spiller , I forgot to mention. Yes I'm developing this code for a test node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running in a test node there are several methods available for reacting on signals.

Their names all start with `testWaitForSignal`. You can simply check CANoe's documentation for details.

For your particular use case, you could use

```
testWaitForSignalMatch(<signal>, <expectedValue>, 20)
```

The call will return latest after 20ms. The return value will either be `1`, which means *the signal had the expected value within 20ms* or `0`, which means *the signal did not have the expected value within 20ms*.

---

When running in a simulation/measurement node, there is no possibility to *wait*, as that would block the simulation.

What you can do in these nodes is to create an event handler like

```
on signal_change <signal>
```

In this event handler you can access the value of the signal by using `$<signal>`.

The current timestamp can be gotten with a call to `timeNowNS()`.

Using this information you could implement your logic in a simulation node.

Comment: Thanks, Its working. Is there any way to do the same in simulation/measurement mode?

Comment: For non-test nodes, there is no possibility to _wait_, as waiting would block the simulation. What you can do in these nodes is to react on signal changes by using an `on signal_change` event handler, get the value of the signal and the timestamp of the change and implement your logic using this information.